# P4Python trouble deleting client/Workspace

Tags: python, python-3.x, perforce, p4v, p4python

I am trying to delete a client but I get the following error :
"Identifiers too long. Must not be longer than 1024 bytes of UTF-8."
My code goes smth like this:

```
  try: 
  client=p4.fetch_client("-S", stream_root, client_name)
  client._root = client_root
  client._client = client_name
  p4.save_client(client)
  p4.client = client_name
  p4.run_sync("-f", root_path) 
  ......
  p4.run("client", "-d", client)
  logging.info("Workspace" + client + "deleted")
```

Any idea if my lines are correct or what could be missing?

Answer (score 1):

`client` in your script is the entire client spec.  The argument to `p4 client -d` is just the client name:

```
p4.run("client", "-d", client_name)
```

Comment: Thank  you very much, one more question I’m also trying to delete the folder I created for my client in my PC in the end of my code, somehow I get error and it doesn' get deleted. My code goes like this:
 `try: 
  client=p4.fetch_client("-S", stream_root, client_name)
  client._root = client_root
  client._client = client_name
  p4.save_client(client)
  p4.client = client_name
  p4.run_sync("-f", root_path) 
  ......
  p4.run("client", "-d", client_name)
  shutil.rmtree(client_root)`
Error :
`return _rmtree_unsafe(path,onerror)
_rmtree(fullname, onerror) 
...`

Comment: That sounds like it's a problem with your `_rmtree_unsafe` function, not anything in the P4 API.  Might want to post a new question.